# How do I chage price value every time I click button?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, vs-web-site-project

I am now making a simple webshop and I am implementing a shopping cart in javascript.
I want to call my function productTotalPrice() which gives me the total price of that item (price of the item * quantity). I want to update the total price every time I click a button(increment button, decrement and delete button).
Here's my productTotalPrice(). I started Javascript 3 days ago so any advise would be nice!

```js
// total price per item calculator
function productTotalPrice() {
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-list");
    var products = document.getElementsByClassName("product");
    for (var i = 0; i <= cartItems.length; i++) {
        // Please improve this if you can!!
        var product = products[i];
        var productdetail = product.children[2];
        var priceElement = productdetail.children[3];
        var productPrice = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace("€", ""));
        var productQuantity = document.getElementsByClassName("cost")[i].value;
        var priceXquantity = productPrice * productQuantity;
        var price = "€" + priceXquantity;
        document.getElementsByClassName("price")[i].innerText = price;
    }
}

var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('vknop');

for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var buttonClicked = event.target;
        buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        productTotalPrice();
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-list">
        <!-- Product #1 -->
        <div class="product">
          <div>
            <p class="vknop" type="button">X</p>
          </div>

          <div class="image">
            <img src="images/mask1.png" alt="mask">
          </div>

          <div class="detail">
            <p>Mask1</p>
            <p>Color:Green</p>
            <p>size:S</p>
            <p>€10.99</p>
          </div>

          <div class="quantity">
            <button class="add" type="button" name="button">
              +
            </button>
            <input class="cost" type="text" name="amount" value="1" id="qtybox">
            <button class="remove" type="button" name="button">
              -
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="price"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is your current code *not* working? It seems like the code you have would do what you're intending. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: provide the html that goes with this

Comment: @dillon The problem is the price only changes when I reload the page. I want change the price everytime after I click the button.

Comment: @paroxyzm The problem is the price only changes when I reload the page. I want change the price everytime after I click the button. I am calling my function inside a function. I get this error when I click a button accroding to my inspector's console. "Uncaught TypeError: productTotalPrice is not a function"

Comment: @DCR I added my html code now.

Comment: Hmmmm... This should work well. Maybe you have productTotalPrice on different file and load it after the first file?

Comment: @S.Wasta I do get the value I want. The only problem is that I need to reload my page to display the new value. And I don't how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implemented logic of your code is correct  , the buttons work as intented

but the problem of having to refresh page everytime  you click a button to display a change in cart value
or no of items can be  fixed by using  Asynchronous Javascript ( AJAX ) rather than basic JS .

YOur code should be modified to take  asynchronous  inputs from the background or not ( in case when user scrolls through the page rather than interacting with the page)

You can learn more about AJAX  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It was in my for loop condition. It had to be products.length and not cartItems.length.Thank you everyone.